# combine codes of find and attr

Tags: jquery

this is just a small issue. Not really a problem. I've got these codes:

```
    $('.gallery a').attr('href', href);
    $('.gallery a').find('img').attr( 'src', dir + '/img/design/' + img );
```

is it possible to combine them something like this?

```
    $('.gallery a').attr('href', href).find('img').attr( 'src', dir + '/img/design/' + img );
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: thats strange... at first it didn't work... but now it does lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) says that `.attr( attributeName, value )` returns [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), so you can chain it like that.

Just remember that not everything is chainable (i.e. you obviously can't chain from functions that have a return value, so check the documentation if you're unsure).

Comment: If it returns jQuery, it's not really chainable, hopefully it returns the collection of elements.